# XML data in asp.net controls

Tags: .net, asp.net, controls

I Have some xml data like

```
`<?xml version='1.0'?>
<lunch-menu>
    <food>
        <name>Cheese Pizza</name>
        <price>$6.95</price>
        <description>Individual deep-dish pizza with lots of mozzarella cheese</description>
        <calories>800</calories>
    </food>
</lunch-menu>'
```

I want to display this data in a textbox/textarea or some other asp.net control with options like collapse tag , copy , paste options. Please help me out to this.

Answer (score 0):

What about [ASP.NET TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z5184w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Control?
It automatically provides you with Collapse feature. And Copy/Paste features you can make yourself by implementing context menu, see [Context menu for TreeView Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/xtreeview.aspx)